# How to limit users to a create only one instance of a node type?

Tags: 7, nodes, users

I know there is [Node Limit](http://drupal.org/project/node_limit) module, but since it is in alpha stage since a rather long time, I am wondering if there is more elegant way to do so which does not need additional modules?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FWIW I've been using Node Limit on a dev site for a few weeks now, it's had thorough testing and seems to work perfectly. I'm using the 'Node Limit Type' and 'Node Limit User of Role' sub-modules.

If you want to implement it yourself, you can't really look anywhere better than inside the Node Limit module itself. It implements [`hook_node_prepare()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_prepare/7) to deny access to the node add form if the user has exceeded the maximum nodes, based on various rules.

A very simple custom implementation might look like this:

```
function MYMODULE_node_prepare($node) {
  if (empty($node->nid) && $node->type == 'the_content_type') {
    // Grab the number of nodes of this type the user has already created.
    $args = array(':type' => 'the_content_type', ':uid' => $GLOBALS['user']->uid);
    $node_count = db_query('SELECT COUNT(nid) FROM {node} WHERE type = :type AND uid = :uid', $args)->fetchField();

    // Get the max allowed number of nodes
    $limit = function_to_get_limit();

    // If the user is at/has exceeded the limit, set a message and send the user
    // off somewhere else.
    if ($limit >= $node_count) {
      drupal_set_message(t('Node limit exceeded'));

      drupal_goto('somewhere');
    }
  }
}
```

You could obviously add further checks in there to make sure the user has a certain role, etc. I'd advise having a flick through the code in the Node Limit module to see how the above could be improved upon.

The above is a 'friendly' way to perform the check (i.e. one that doesn't just throw out a 403 page). If you want to be more militant, you could put roughly the same code in a [`hook_node_access()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7) implementation instead:

```
function MYMODULE_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
  if ($op == 'create' && $node->type == 'the_content_type') {
    // Grab the number of nodes of this type the user has already created.
    $args = array(':type' => 'the_content_type', ':uid' => $account->uid);
    $node_count = db_query('SELECT COUNT(nid) FROM {node} WHERE type = :type AND uid = :uid', $args)->fetchField();

    // Get the max allowed number of nodes
    $limit = function_to_get_limit();

    // If the user us at/has exceeded the limit, set a message and send the user
    // off somewhere else.
    if ($limit >= $node_count) {
      return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
    }

    return NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW;
  }

  return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I only wanted users to be able to create a single node of a content type on my site.  In my use case, every user needed to have a node (basically using nodes as profiles), so I used the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to automatically create the node and a relation (with the Relation module) to the user upon account validation (though the relation might not be necessary in your case).

Then, I gave users permission to edit their own nodes of the content type, but not create them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can study the code of the [Only One](https://www.drupal.org/project/onlyone) module to see a simple way to accomplish this.

> The Only One module allows the creation of Only One node per language
>   in the selected content types for this configuration.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function onlyone_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $onlyone_content_types = variable_get('onlyone_node_types');
  // Getting the name of the node type.
  $node_type = $form['type']['#value'];
  // Verifying if the new node should by onlyone.
  if (isset($onlyone_content_types) && in_array($node_type, $onlyone_content_types, TRUE)) {
    $node = $form_state['node'];
    // If we are trying to create a new node.
    if (!isset($node->nid) || isset($node->is_new)) {
      $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
      $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
        ->entityCondition('bundle', $node_type);
      // The site is multilingual?
      if (drupal_multilingual()) {
        global $language;
        $query->propertyCondition('language', $language->language);
      }
      // Executing the query.
      $result = $query->execute();
      // If we have one node, then redirect to the edit page.
      if (isset($result['node'])) {
        $nid = array_keys($result['node']);
        $nid = $nid[0];
        drupal_goto('node/' . $nid . '/edit');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

<sup>Disclosure: I'm the maintainer of the module [Only One](https://www.drupal.org/project/onlyone).</sup>